# Erroneous sym type: EmbeddedSolrServer.query

Tags: java, exception, solr, apache-tomee

Im having a problem implementing the EmbeddedSolrServer from Solr, everything it seems to be in the right place, and its compiling and everything but when it tries to make a request>

```
QueryResponse rsp = solrServer.getSolrServer().query(query);
```

I get the following exception:

```
avax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested    exception is: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: EmbeddedSolrServer.query
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:368)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:288)
at com.polyglong.solr.SolrServerController$LocalBeanProxy.getResult(com/polyglong/solr/SolrServerController.java)
at com.polyglong.solr.SolrServerTest.getResults(SolrServerTest.java:29)
```

I am using TomEE, and Solr 3.6.0

Comment: If you can update with the full stack trace, that'd be great

Comment: I could fix it, just making a full import again! thanks anyways.